# Checkbox uncheck and check Other field is getting blank

Tags: jquery, jsf, checkbox

```
<tr:table id="UserTable" width="100%" ......>
  <tr:selectBooleanCheckbox id="ctrl_select" value="#{user.isSelected}" autoSubmit="true" valueChangeListener="#{userAction.onUserSelected}" onchange="submit()"/>
  <tr:inputText id="effDate" simple="true" value="#{user.effectiveDate}" disabled="#{!user.isSelected}"/>
```

Action: onUserSelect based on business logic I am setting effective Date.

1: When I check the checkbox its submited and effDate is enabled.
2: I clear the date
3: Uncheck the checkbox. I can see the date and its disabled.
4. check the checkbox again, Date field is enabled But the effDate is blank.

I do not want the `effDate` to be blank. I believe the UpdateModel is called. Is there a way not to set the value to blank??

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering the component **tr:inputText** and updating the same component. I doubt will work.

Because that component might not have been added to/present in component tree by the time you are updating. This is because the component might not be added to the DOM tree at the time you are trying to update the **booleancheckbox**.

So use a different component at the bottom such as panel or panelgroup and update it.

JSF Code:

```
<tr:table id="UserTable" width="100%" ......>
      <tr:selectBooleanCheckbox id="ctrl_select" value="#{user.isSelected}" 
      autoSubmit="true" valueChangeListener="#{userAction.onUserSelected}" 
       onchange="submit()" update="effDatePanel"/>

<tr:panel id="effDatePanel">
   <tr:inputText id="effDate" simple="true" value="#{user.effectiveDate}" 
     disabled="#{!user.isSelected}"/>
</tr:panel>
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: I didnt try this. However I removed submit() and used partialTrigger which seems to work fine. Also there is no update attribute on tr:selectBooleanCheckbox